# iOS6 Game Center Authentication not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I am able to log into GameCenter with iOS7, but with iOS6 I can't log in:

```
 -(void)authenticateLocalUser
{
__weak GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
{
    if(viewController)
    {
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if(localPlayer.isAuthenticated == YES)
    {
        [localPlayer generateIdentityVerificationSignatureWithCompletionHandler:^(NSURL *publicKeyUrl, NSData *signature, NSData *salt, uint64_t timestamp, NSError *error) {
            if(error != nil)
            {
                return; //some sort of error, can't authenticate right now
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"game center disabled");
    }
};
```

}

It will throw Game Center Disabled..

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to have GameCenter already open.

Comment: Tim you mean you have to have the separate Game Center app open for it to work??..... I am having the same issue as you :(